# JSP Error: FileUtils cannot be resolved

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I am trying to:

1. Read the xml data from an URL and save it to a file called agencies.xml
2. Parse the xml data in the newly created file and display the data.

My attempt:

```
<%@ page import="org.w3c.dom.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.xml.parsers.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@ page import="java.net.URL"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.*"%>

<% 
try {
URL url = new URL("http://10.12.123.12:1234/jspdemo/xmldata/xml_agency.jsp");
File destination = new File("agencies.xml");

// Copy bytes from the URL to the destination file.
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, destination);

} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();   
  }

%>

<%
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("agencies.xml");

NodeList agency = doc.getElementsByTagName("agency");
NodeList agencyId = doc.getElementsByTagName("agency_id");
NodeList agencyName = doc.getElementsByTagName("agency_name");

System.out.println("id:" + agencyId);
System.out.println("name:" + agencyName);
%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Read XML Data</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<form method="POST" action="ReadXML.jsp">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label>Agency ID</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="filterName" style="text-align:center;">
        <% for (int i=0; i<agency.getLength(); i++) { %>
            <option value=><%= agencyId.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()%></option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <label>Agency Name</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="filterAge" style="text-align:center;">
        <% for (int i=0; i<agency.getLength(); i++) { %>
            <option value=><%= agencyName.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()%></option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>
  <a href="">Generate</a>
  </td>
  </tr>

</form>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

and the full stacktace are:

```
    Aug 30, 2017 9:25:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/jspdemo] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /ReadXML.jsp
FileUtils cannot be resolved
12: File destination = new File("agencies.xml");
13: 
14: // Copy bytes from the URL to the destination file.
15: FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, destination);
16: 
17: } catch (IOException e) {
18:      e.printStackTrace();   


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /ReadXML.jsp
FileUtils cannot be resolved
12: File destination = new File("agencies.xml");
13: 
14: // Copy bytes from the URL to the destination file.
15: FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, destination);
16: 
17: } catch (IOException e) {
18:      e.printStackTrace();   


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:363)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:338)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:325)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The errors occur at the step 1. Is it due to the class FileUtils does not work with JSP? Since it works under .java class.

I am using Eclipse with jdk1.8 and tomcat8. Please suggest me what to do in order to solve the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clean and redeploy the project, make sure there's a commons-io jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your webapp in tomcat server

Comment: @RC It displays the same error.

Comment: Well, the program works on jdeveloper. I don't know what's wrong with eclipse.